# Android Spinner Saving Last Selected Option

Tags: android

I have a Spinner in my Activity with a list of Options. By default my first Item on the list is in Selected State when I start the Activity.

Assume My List has `<Circle> <Square> <Rectangle> <Triangle>`

When Activity is created for the first time Circle is Selected. Suppose I select Rectangle. Then I navigate to another Activity and then recreate the Activity. My selection is restored to the first Item again. How can I save my previous selected option.

Answer (score 1):

What are the Object types in your list?  Strings?

Try overriding `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`

This answer has a nice example: [Saving Android Activity state using Save Instance State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state)